# Jquery creating a function that will be used for input validation

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-selectors

I have  a text box here that displaying error when the input is invalid. I'm wondering how will make a function that will display the error in two span so i will prevent redundancy. Here is my html file

```
<div class="form-group row has-feedback" id="username-group">
            <div class="col-sm-4"><label class="control-label">Username</label></div>
            <div class="col-sm-8">
              <div>
                <input type="text" name="username" id="username" value="<?php echo $username;?>" class="form-control user-required" required>
                <span id="username-feedback" class="glyphicon form-control-feedback hidden"></span>
              </div>
              <div><span class="small font-design error_span"><?php if(isset($usernameErr)){echo $usernameErr;} ?></span></div>
            </div>
          </div>
```

And here is what i've done so far in the span with class error_span

```
function checkEmpty(id){
  if($(id).val()==""){
    $(id)[0].setCustomValidity('Please fill out this field');
    $(id).closest('.form-group').find('.error_span').text("Please fill out this field").removeClass("hidden").addClass("text text-danger");
  }
  else{
    $(id)[0].setCustomValidity('');
    $(id).closest('.form-group').find('.error_span').text("").addClass("hidden").addClass("text text-danger");
  }
}
$(".user-required").blur(function(){
  checkEmpty("#" + $(this).attr('id'));
});
```

And my code that i think will be redundant is here. It will add a feedback icon to the text box.

```
if($("#username").val()==existing){
          $("#username-feedback").addClass("glyphicon-remove");
          $("#username-feedback").removeClass("glyphicon-ok hidden");
          $("#username-group").removeClass("has-success");
          $("#username-group").addClass("has-error");
          $("#username")[0].setCustomValidity('username not available');
          $("#username").closest('.form-group').find('.error_span').text("username not available").removeClass("hidden").addClass("text text-danger");
        }
        else{
          $("#username-feedback").addClass("glyphicon-ok");
          $("#username-feedback").removeClass("glyphicon-remove hidden");
          $("#username-group").removeClass("has-error");
          $("#username-group").addClass("has-success");
          $("#username")[0].setCustomValidity('');
          $("#username").closest('.form-group').find('.error_span').text("").addClass("hidden");
        }
$("#username").blur(function(){
    if($("#username").val()==""){
      $("#username-feedback").addClass("glyphicon-remove");
      $("#username-feedback").removeClass("glyphicon-ok hidden");
      $("#username-group").removeClass("has-success");
      $("#username-group").addClass("has-error");
      $("#username")[0].setCustomValidity('Please fill out this field');
      $("#username").closest('.form-group').find('.error_span').text("Please fill out this field").removeClass("hidden").addClass("text text-danger");
    }
  });
```

can someone help me cause im having trouble in creating a function because I have small knowledge about jquery selector

Comment: Can you be more specific about what your problem is?

Comment: All of these code is validation of input. I'm will used this lot of in all of my form I want to create reusable function for this but i dont know what to do I already created one function : checkEmpty() but i want to add the has-feedback class to another span and i cant think of jquery selector that can be used

Answer (score 0):

```js
function saveForm(){
  
  var lenName = $('#nameInput').val().length;
  
  
  if (lenName <= 0) { 
   $( ".alert" ).text("Error submiting the form, please fill all the fields!");
            $( ".alert" ).show();
        }
  else{
   $( ".alert" ).hide();
   $( "#form" ).submit();
  }
 }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<form class="form" action="test.html" method="post" id="form">

   <div class="alert" style="display: none;"></div>
  <input name="name" type="text" class="form-control" id="nameInput" placeholder="Name">
 
    <br>
 <button type="button" onclick="saveForm()">Submit</button>

</form>
```

You can do more verification in the function this is a simple example.